# Найти в файле слово и вывести строку на которой это слово находится

Tags: python, linux

Я пишу скрипт проверки конфигураций для студентов и мне нужно из файла /etc/nsswitch найти строку которая содержит слово hosts и вывести ее на терминал

Мои неудачные попытки внизу

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#from os import *

#print(`cat /etc/nsswitch.conf`)
#ho = 'hosts'
#inp = iter(open('/etc/nsswitch.conf').readlines())
#for i in iter(open(inp)):
#       if ho in i:
#       print(i)
#with open('etc/nsswitch.conf') as inp:
#       for i in inp:
#       if ho in i:
#               print(i)
```

Comment: видимо, вы заинтересованы не в решении, а именно в использовании программы python. иначе давно бы уже воспользовались специально для этого написанной программой grep: `$ grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf`

Comment: Последний вариант должен работать, только путь к файлу исправьте `with open('/etc/nsswitch.conf')`.